# Condition on request SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have a table SQL and I fill it from an Excel File. The problem is many fields are repeated. For example:

```
FOURNITURE      MFC       SERIE  
FOURNITURE      MFC       SERIE 
FOURNITURE      MFC       SERIE
```

Here in my table, I find just one line. It jumps up all the rest. However, I need to get all the lines.

My request is:

```
if ($articleid == 'DIEPRESTATION' || $articleid == 'DIEDIVBIEN' || $articleid == 'DIEDIVERS' ){
    if(!($this->_db->query("INSERT INTO `article` (`ID_Article`, `Designiation`, `Ident`, `ID_LRU`) VALUES ('".$articleid."', '".$designation."', '".$ident."', '".$IdLRU."');"))){   
        if ($LRU != 'new'){
            return $this->_db->query(" UPDATE  `FLOOSE`.`article` SET  `ID_LRU` =  '".$IdLRU."' WHERE  `article`.`ID_Article` =  '".$articleid."' AND  `article`.`Designiation` =  '".$designation."' AND  `article`.`Ident` =  '".$ident."' LIMIT 1 ;");
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

How can I change it or take a test to recover all the lines?
Thank you.

Comment: you're saying that despite having multiple identical rows in the Excel file you only end up with one row for each in the db ?

Comment: yes exactly. I find just one line.

Comment: It sounds like your insert statement is failing, perhaps you have a unique key constraint on one or more table columns ?

Comment: I don't have a constraint of a unique key. the primary keys are 'ID_Article' and 'Designiation'.

Comment: I think I do not understand you by "unique key constraint" ?